# How do I copy a struct Array?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to go about creating a copy of my array. How do I make a copy of my struct Person array with it's original content?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
};

const int arraySize = 2;
Person arrayM[arraySize];
void createArray(Person personArray[], int SIZE);
void printArray(Person personArray[], int SIZE);
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    createArray(arrayM, arraySize);
    printArray(arrayM, arraySize);
    return 0;
}

void createArray(Person personArray[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        int age1 = rand() % 50 + 1;
        int age2 = rand() % 25 + 1;
        personArray[i].age = age1;
        personArray[i].age = age2;
    }
}

void printArray(Person personArray[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << personArray[i].age << " " << personArray[i].age;
    }
}

void copyStruct(Person personArray[], int SIZE)
{
    int copyOfArray[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
       ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and C++11

Comment: Consider using a stl container like `std::vector<Person>`

Comment: Important point: regardless of how you ":copy" personArray...your variable "int copyOfArray[]"  *ceases to exist* when you exit copyStruct().  You *MUST* allocate your "copy" differently if you wish to use it outside of copyStruct()...

Comment: Unrelated, It would seem `personArray[i].age = age1` is somewhat pointless, since you `personArray[i].age = age2` on the very next line, thus also making the calculation of `age1` itself pointless. And you're missing `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, `int copyOfArray[SIZE]` is supposed to be `Person copyOfArray[SIZE]` a just replace your ??? with

```
copyOfArray[i] = personArray[i];
```

or use std::array as suggested by basile

Answer (score 2):

More idiomatic, using a `std` algorithm. I also re-typed copyOfArray to `Person`.

```
void copyStruct(Person personArray[], int SIZE)
{
    Person copyOfArray[SIZE];
    std::copy(
        personArray,
        personArray + SIZE,
        +copyOfArray // + forces the array-to-pointer decay. 
    );
    // Do something with it
}
```

However, as already stated, you should rather use `std::vector` or `std::array`, which overload `operator =`.

Comment: Use of `std::vector<>` has the added benefit that it removes the need for non-standard VLA-extensions, which this currently requires.

Comment: Is the `+copyOfArray` intentional? If so, you may want to explain that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was thinking C++14, but in fact it's not in.

Comment: @MSalters it's there to force array-to-pointer decay. I don't have a C++ compiler at hand to try it without, so better safe than compile error. - Thanks for the edit !

Comment: @Quentin you don't need the `+`. Its fine with just `copyOfArray` as the final param. And the vector solution is simply `std::vector<Person> copyOfArray(personArray, personArray+SIZE);`, though I would have much warmer feelings about that had the OP used `std::size_t` for the sequence length parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Define the 'copyStruct' function like that:

```
void copyStruct(Person destOfArray[], Person srcArray[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        destOfArray[i].age = srcArray[i].age; 
        destOfArray[i].name = srcArray[i].name;
    }
}
```

And use the function like that:

```
Person copyOfArray[arraySize];
copyStruct(copyOfArray, arrayM, arraySize);

// Now print the content of 'copyOfArray' using your 'printArray' function
printArray(copyOfArray, arraySize);
```

Comment: Why bother with `copyStruct()`? `Person::Person(Person const&)`, the implicit copy constructor works just fine.

Comment: @MSalters: Because the post owner wanted to copy a struct array, not a single struct.

Comment: Sure, but if you do have a working copy ctor, you can use `std::copy` to copy an array. Copying fields is only needed if the  implicit copy ctor is not working for some reason.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, now I've understand what you wanted to say.